# Can I get an EASA Class 1 medical with high astigmatism?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical

I have high astigmatism (5 dioptres) and myopia (under the limit). Is it possible to acquire a Class 1 medical certificate? If I recall correctly, it's up to the ophthalmologist to judge whether I should get the certificate.

If not, is there something equivalent to the FAA SODA? I know about a medical flight test but I have no idea how it works and if it's possible to do it in order to acquire a Class 1 medical certificate.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an equivalent of FAA SODA under EASA regulations.
The final decision is up to the ophtalmologist (in agreement with the AME). You should bring to the medical examinations all supporting material to help him take an informed decision.
In case you won't pass the medical examination, you will be given right to appleal. For the appealing procedure you will have to prepare a dossier to persuade that you are fit for the EASA Class 1 medical.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! At least that gives me some hope. If you dont mind me asking what do you mean by the dossier for the appealing process? What should I include there apart from medical examinations?

Comment: It depends on your case, you may need to consult with someone expert in Air Law. You may include medical exams, reports from doctors, reports from flight instructors. Think of it as a way of proving that you won't be an hazard in the sky